# fseek and fscan give wrong results from .DAT file in C++

Tags: c++, fopen, scanf, fseek, fgetc

I have a .dat file which is being updated constantly. I want to get data from the latest line in the file. But I obtain inaccurate results. Here is the myfile.DAT :

```
# Time  forces(pressure, viscous) moment(pressure, viscous)
0.005   (((2 10 4) (3 6 0)) ((12 60 -13) (4.88 0.5 -0.32)))
0.01    (((2 20 2) (4 7 3)) ((0.0024 1 -70) (40 6000 -1200)))
```

And here is the C++ code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  FILE * force;
  force = fopen("file.dat", "r");
  float timestep;
  float fxp;
  float fyp;
  float fzp;
  float fxv;
  float fyv;
  float fzv;
  float mxp;
  float myp;
  float mzp;
  float mxv;
  float myv;
  float mzv;

  char c;

  fseek(force,-285,SEEK_END);

  while(c != '\n')
  {
    c = fgetc(force);
  }

  fscanf(force, "%f    ((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f)) ((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f))", &timestep, &fxp, &fyp, &fzp, &fxv, &fyv, &fzv, &mxp, &myp, &mzp, &mxv, &myv, &mzv);

  fclose(force);

  float ftotal = fxp + fxv;

  std::cout << "Here is f_total = " << ftotal << " N" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the result :

```
Here is f_total = 0 N
```

Obviously it's wrong. It must be 2 + 4 = 6.

Comment: What is the "latest line" in a file that is being constantly updated?

Comment: Funny that you `#include <fstream>` and you don't use any of the `std::*fstream` classes

Comment: If the file is being written as you read it, the last line might not be complete, because the writer has part of it buffered.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As you see the Timestep, it is being updated. Timestep goes on and on. So I want to use the last line I mean tha last Timestep.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. But here I simplified the problem. And .DAT file is constant. So it must should give me 2 + 4 = 6. In other words, the example above is simple and has 2 lines.

Comment: Check the return value of `fscanf()`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried std::cout << fscanf() and it gave me 1. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fscanf` format string is:

```
"%f    ((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f)) ((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f))"
```

but should be:

```
"%f    (((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f)) ((%f %f %f) (%f %f %f)))"
```

---

**Edit:** This is most likely not the best way to do it (going 2 back, 1 forward) but check if it works with this change:

```
fseek(force, -1, SEEK_END);

while (c != '\n')
{
    c = fgetc(force);
    fseek(force, -2, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it gave me 'Here is f_total = 5 N'. It must be 6.

Comment: It gives me 6 and I created that .dat file with exactly the same content. Compile the code you posted here, create new file with posted content and try again.

Comment: I created new .dat and c++ code. The result is still 5. Even I changed the values of the file. It always gives 5.

Comment: I think I have problem with fseek -285. Because this code gives me result of the first line not the last one.

Comment: @ordinary Each line is about 60 characters long. So -285 will go back 4 lines in the file.

Comment: @mpiatek Thank you very much. I tried with your last one, it gives me 0. Then I tried your last edit with Barmar's tip(cout << fscan) Then it gave me 1.

Comment: [this code](https://paste.ofcode.org/5cDDmjcJzVfvaVRTAXEKCC) gives you 0? Paste the actual code you are compiling somewhere and post a link please.

Comment: @ordinary have you tried the code I posted in the last comment? Is the issue resolved?

Comment: I appreciate your valuable effort. But unfortunately your last code which you sent by link gave me 0. Thank you again.

Comment: @ordinary could you please double check if the last record in your file is the same as the one you posted here? Then could you upload your .dat file somewhere?

Comment: @ordinary does your file have `\n` as a last character? In other words is there a new line at the end of the file?

Comment: Actually my file goes on and on. I mean the last line which starts 0.01 changes 0.015, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.035 ...
...

So there are lots of lines, but to simplify my question, I posted it's just 2 lines in the question.

Comment: @ordinary my question is - in the file you use for testing (and in real file that is generated by something else) what is the last character? Is it \n or the file ends with last bracket?

Comment: It is just parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

1 fscanf returns the number of fields scanned - so a quick check is to add "int n = fscanf(...." -- then check that "n" is what you think it should be. This can save you a lot of head-scratching.

2: Better than assuming the line length with the seek from the end, scan for \n from the beginning of the file, then seek back to the last before doing the fscanf - this would also let you easily pick a specific line number. The following will scan the whole file, then seek back to the last line (assumes that the file doesn't have a \n as the last character)

```
int lineno = 1;
int lastLine = 0;
while(c != EOF)
{
    c = fgetc(force);
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        ++lineno;
        lastLine = ftell(force);
    }
}
printf("%d lines, pos=%d\n", lineno, lastLine);
fseek(force, lastLine, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Thank you. I combined your code with the problem. Now I get 
4 lines, pos=182
Here is f_total = 0 N 

By the way as you said, I think the real problem in here is to define -285. I tried this number with -65 and no problem. It gave me the correct answer. I will try to find a solution and report here later.